# Fast access to private array field

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, oop

I have the `Simulator` class, that contains positions (`_pos`), velocities (`_vel`) and accelerations (`_acc`) of particles. With the help of extensions (based on the `Simulator.Extension` class), I want to add a thermostat, barostat and so on to the `Simulator`. For this, I need access to positions, velocities and accelerations from extensions. Please, tell me the best way to do this.

```
public class Simulator
{
    private Vector3[] _pos;
    private Vector3[] _vel;
    private Vector3[] _acc;

    public class Extension
    {
        protected Simulator Simulator { get; set; }

        protected Extension(Simulator simulator)
        {
            Simulator = simulator ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(simulator));
        }

        public abstract void DoWork();
    }

    ...
}
```

Specifically, the extensions should be able to read a certain element of the `_pos` (or `_vel`, `_acc`), modify it, and add or remove arrays elements. I need a fast and thread-safe mechanism.

Comment: Why `Extension` is a child of `Simulator` and not a, say, derived class from it ?

Comment: @Tigran because I wanted to make a `protected Vector3[] Pos => Simulator._pos` reference in nested `Extension` class.

Comment: I can only agree: Your design is very confusing. You might have made some fundamental mistakes at designing this whole thing. Usually I would make "Particle" a class or struct. And then make a array of "Particle". Rather then 3 seperate arrays.

Comment: @Christopher How will this approach affect performance? In my code there will be many operations of integration of equations of motion. And I still need to somehow get access to the array with the particles.

Comment: While your focuss on speed is admirable, it might be plain excessive. I think it is time for you to read the speed rant: http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/ You can always do speed optimisations later. But first you have to have actually working, tested code that does the job at all.

Comment: @Christopher In the suggested variant I need to make a reference to the `List<Particle>` in the `Extension`?

Comment: What exactly is the Extenion class there for? There seems to be no obvious reason for it to be here. What does it do what Simulator does not? Why is it a child class of Simualtor? Why does it not have the Array of Vectors/particles it needs to work with?

Comment: @Christopher According to my initial idea, I wanted to create a `protected Vector3[] Pos => Simulator._pos` (`_pos` is `private`) reference to an array in the `Extension` class. This would give access to positions from extensions. For this, the `Extension` was created as a nested class. Extensions were made in order to add certain functionality to the `Simulator`, which is not always required.

Comment: @Christopher The extension would work with the parameters of the particles, and it would give certain effects in the simulation. For example, temperature control of the simulated system.

Comment: Sorry, but your explanation simply makes no sense. You should propably go back to the drawing board. You might be in a XY problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem